# Remove push notification history entries from Parse

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, push-notification

Is there a way to remove push notification history entries from Parse? I didn't find anything in their documentation. I did not see an option in their web console to remove push notification history either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe setting them to expire is all you have control over at this point. The only ones you can truly delete are scheduled push notifications (but only if it hasn't been processed yet). Someone else can correct me if I'm wrong, but I also believe the notifications simply disappear after a certain amount of time, based on my experiences, but it may also because I use the [expire feature](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#options-expiry/iOS) [which is a feature that parse stops trying to send a specific notification because it may not be relevant anymore to the user if they've had their device off for weeks etc. for example: a super savings sale at JC Penny for 1 weekend only]

Comment: Thank you - that's crazy. You'd think that deleting the push notifications history would be great feature to have. Unfortunately i didn't set an expiration date for two test push notifications i sent.

Comment: Well payloads don't hold that much data so it's no harm, especially when they simply disappear after a while, but I do know it has been added to their feature request, so at least they are aware theres a need for it!

Comment: Check this out, I was able to reset the count of push notifications on the device, but it doesn't necessarily remove them from parse.     UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

Answer (score 2):

Click the individual push entry under the push tab in Parse and then there is a delete button in the top right as well as useful stats about the push notification.
[image]

Comment: Ugh. Not worth my time to delete them one by one. But a nice work around!